# Correction for uncertainty of multiplications and divisions

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

The conventional means of obtaining uncertainty of $c$ where $c = a \cdot b$ is adding percentage uncertainty of $a$ and $b$. This method seems to have a flaw as shown below (please excuse me if I am yet to get to the correction in my studies).

You have a square and a very bad ruler and want to find the area of the square. You find that the dimensions of the square are $L = 4\;\mathrm{cm} \pm 2\;\mathrm{cm}$ and $W = 4\;\mathrm{cm} \pm 2\;\mathrm{cm}$. The percentage uncertainty for each of these measurements is $50\%$, you add the two $50\%$ uncertainties to get $100\%$ percentage uncertainty. 
$$
A = 16\;\mathrm{cm}^2 \pm 16\;\mathrm{cm}^2
$$
I was wondering if there was a method of correction to avoid problems like these arising.

Comment: The possible results range from 4 to 36, not 0 to 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encounter is that you are applying the rule that is applicable to "linear addition" of uncertainty, to non-linear applications (multiplication).

**Valid application ..** $(4 \frac{+}{-}2)$ **+** $(8 \frac{+}{-}3) = 12 \frac{+}{-}5 $ (7 -> 17 range)
**Invalid application** $(4 \frac{+}{-}2)$ **x** $(8 \frac{+}{-}3) = 32 \frac{+}{-}? $

To obtain the correct answer, when multiplying, you have to use the rules of multiplication, which will give you:  $(4 \frac{+}{-}2)$ x $(8 \frac{+}{-}3) = 32 \frac{+34}{-22} $ (10 -> 66 range).